# Best way to plug a mangled old floor drain?

Tags: basement

I’ve got an old steel 1 1/2” drain line in my basement slab. I suspected it was there because of the little circular concrete pour. I removed the concrete and found the drain plugged with paper that was damp. The drain has long been unnecessary and happens to be right where I want to run a bottom plate for a new basement wall.

What’s the best way to plug it for good? Silicone? Great stuff? Both? I don’t know how far the main line is from the pipe end so I don’t want to pour in anything that could drip into the main line and block it.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: A wad of paper or something else so you can pour the plug, and hydraulic cement, would seem an obvious choice -- so I'm not sure why you removed what was there.

Comment: Stuff either paper ball or polystyrene. Then pour in stiff mixture, so it doesnt run like water. I often done this myself.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the answer was already in a comment. I'm fleshing it out and adding some prep instruction.

First, plug the pipe with something that will block water. It can be temporary, like the wad of paper which was already there. You want to leave the overall capacity at a gallon or two for the pipe and surrounding low spot.

Second, prepare around the hole. Remove any loose material. Using a cold chisel, rotohammer, or similar, make sure that the edge of the repair area has a quarter inch shelf at all points. This will help you to make a smooth patch and avoid having the edges be too weak to stay in place. Make sure to wear safety goggles and properly deal with any dust. Silica dust is no joke.

Last, mix up some All-Crete or other hydraulic cement to flowable consistency. Pour enough in to the hole to fill up nearly to your edge. Let it settle for a minute, then finish off the pour to the level of the surrounding floor. It should settle in to place as a permanent repair.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a ton for all the replies! I followed KMJ’s direction nearly everywhere. After cutting out the whole, I discovered yet another strange drain that points to nowhere.

I cut the pipe so it wasn’t so close to the top of the pour. I used great stuff to plug the deep inside and then mixed hydraulic cement. Took a whole 20lb bucket.

Here’s some pics!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks pretty solid from here.